# Url returns: 'Route [login] not defined' without associated with any middleware

Tags: laravel

I'm testing an *API* that I'm developing, in localhost I can do a particular request and it returns everything to me 'ok'. When doing the same test on a server, it is returning a '*path [login] not defined*.' Being that I am not associating any authentication *middleware* to my *API* and neither associating it in the constructor of my *controller*.

```
 public function getListById($id)
 {
    $user = DB::table('dbTestes')->where('id', $id)->get();
    return response()->json($user);
 }


//Api route

Route::get('/ponto/edit/{id}', 'PontoController@getListById');
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- I'm using the same database.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with middleware. Something in your app is trying to generate the route called `login`. Query your app code for the string `login` and see if you can find where it is. It's possible that a view or exception handler somewhere could be trying to generate that route.

Comment: This only happens when I try to access this method. Others, such as insert, delete, work without any failures.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/ponto/edit/{id}', 'PontoController@getListById')->name('login');
```